# AttributeError: module 'whois' has no attribute 'whois' [library is already installed] - Python 3.6.7

Tags: python-3.x

```
import whois

url = 'https://www.wirecard.com.br'
w = whois.whois(url)
owner = w.owner
print("Owner:", owner)

>>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pricylla.couto\Desktop\tentantiva.py", line 5, in <module>
    w = whois.whois(url)
AttributeError: module 'whois' has no attribute 'whois'
```

I changed my computer and installed the same version of Python, and I am using the same code I used in my old computer. I installed all the libraries, but I got this error!!!

Comment: Make sure you are using python-whois and not whois package.

Comment: I have done that, still not working.

Comment: I had the same problem and it only worked with Python 2.7 . I had to uninstall Py3 , install python-whois and then I was able to use the whois library.